# Set table data color in CSS file

Tags: html, css

When setting the color of a table data field with this

```
<td class='td_7_1' style='background-color: #FA58F4' >Hallo</td>
```

it is working.

But when I use this

```
<td class='td_7_1' >Hallo</td>
```

and place this in my CSS file

```
td.td_7_1
{
width : 15%;
background-color: : #FA58F4;
}
```

it is not working (and yes, my CSS file is linked with this):

```
<link href="overzicht.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any help is welcome!

Comment: html and css is fine (http://jsfiddle.net/bBymz/) problem could be the `<link href="... ` are you sure the overzicht.css file is located at the right place?

Answer (score 3):

Remove an extra `:` from css

```
background-color:  #FA58F4;
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/wikigadu/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your css has two :

Change it to:

```
td.td_7_1
{
width : 15%;
background-color: #FA58F4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
td.td_7_1
{
width : 15%;
background-color: #FA58F4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css code

```
.td_7_1
{
width : 15%;
background-color: #FA58F4;
}
```